# Floating in Rails 3.1 and Blueprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-float, blueprint-css

I have problem with transfer layout to Rails project, in other catalog all is okey, site working nice, but when I do it in Rails, when I add "span-n", or "column" or some other it spoils ; / First it do float to right in grid (I don't change anything!) and rest is not in it's place

I load stylesheet like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "blueprint/screen", :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "blueprint/print", :media => 'print' %>
```

Can anybody help me? I am not webmaster and dig in css code is nightmare for me ; )

Comment: Okey, I solve problem. I must delete stylesheet to application with was default in app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

In my layouts folder, I have a file called _stylesheets.html.erb that contains the following

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

And then in my header.html.erb file, I have the following line in the  section of the html:

```
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
```

That should get you up and running.